# How to write regex properly in re_path django 3

Tags: python-3.x, django, regex, web, pycharm

The problem with my code is that I keep getting a "page not found (404) error, the path 'post/...' does not match" when I try to click on a hyperlink on my posts page. I made 3 posts. Could it be the regex? Because I'm currently not good at regex.
How can I match the views.py to the correct path in urlpatterns?

My urls.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path

from blog import views as blog_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/', blog_views.post),
    
    re_path(r'^post(.*)/$', blog_views.post),

    path('about/'. blog_views.about),

    path('', blog_views.index),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

My views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Post

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html', {'posts': posts})

def post(request, slug):
    print(slug)
    return render ('post.html',{'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
re_path(r'post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', blog_views.posts),
```

Do you really need to use `re_path` here? It would be simpler to use `path`:

```
path('post/<slug:slug>/', blog_views.post),
```

Comment: In the example I used in learning django the instructor used regex in the path but that was django 1.7 and I'm on Django 3, so there was a mix-up

Comment: I've also tried your code but I'm now getting a TypeError-> join() argument must be str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

Comment: Django 1.7 is really old - it might be better to find a different book/tutorial to learn Django, otherwise you might spend a lot of time updating the code to run with new versions of Django.

Comment: I can't tell what's causing the TypeError unless I see your code and the full traceback. My answer was missing commas and a slash until a moment ago, but I don't think that would cause the problem.